# What's wrong with this Sinatra / Ruby code?

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

Could someone be kind enough to help me figure out why the simple code below just won't display the form content (or any content) after the form is filled & submitted? I wanted to practice dynamic forms with Sinatra from scratch, mirrored some existing working code. But mine just doesn't work.

fam.rb (below)

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/fam_form' do 
    family_names = %w(ma pa sis bro dog cat)
    erb :fam_form
end

post '/fam_list' do
    @ma = params[:ma]
    @pa = params[:pa]
    @sis = params[:sis]
    @bro = params[:bro]
    @dog = params[:dog]
    @cat = params[:cat] 
    erb :fam_list
end
```

fam_form.erb (below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>family form</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form method="POST" action="/fam_list">
     <p>Ma: <input type="text" name="ma"></p>
     <p>Pa: <input type="text" name="pa"></p>
     <p>Sis: <input type="text" name="sis"> </p>
     <p>Bro: <input type="text" name="bro"> </p>
     <p>Dog: <input type="text" name="dog"></p>
     <p>Cat: <input type="text" name="cat"></p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

fam_list.erb (below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fam List</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>My Family Members </h1>
    <p>Ma  <%= @ma %> </p>
    <p>Pa <%= @pa %> </p>
    <p>Sis <%=@sis %> </p>
    <p>Bro <%=@bro %> </p>
    <p>Dog <%=@dog %> </p>
    <p>Cat <%=@cat %> </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At a first glance, it _should_ be working. Show params of your POST request.

Comment: Thank you! I saw your comment and went back & tried again-yes, it worked. Aside from restarting Chrome, nothing had changed. Perhaps something went wrong with Chrome.